# Копирование пикселей в Bitmap

Tags: android, android-sdk, activity

Нужно получить пиксели из одного imageview и занести пиксели в другой imageview. Есть изображение состоящие из white и black цветов. Но после выполнения кода изображение перезаписывается некорректно.

```
    int arrayPixels[][] = new int[200][200];
    int width = mImageViewHaosCenter.getMeasuredWidth();
    int height = mImageViewHaosCenter.getMeasuredHeight();
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mImageViewHaosCenter.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++){
        for (int m = 0; m < height; m++){
            int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(i, m);
            int isBlack = 0;
            if (pixel == Color.WHITE)
                isBlack = 0;
            else if (pixel == Color.BLACK)
                isBlack = 1;
            arrayPixels[i][m] = isBlack;
        }
    }
    Bitmap bitmapBottom = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 200, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++){
        for (int m = 0; m < 200; m++){
            if (arrayPixels[i][m] == 0)
                bitmapBottom.setPixel(i, m, Color.WHITE);
            else if (arrayPixels[i][m] == 1)
                bitmapBottom.setPixel(i, m, Color.BLACK);
        }
    }
    mImageViewHaosBottom.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmapBottom));
}
```

Результат представлен на картинке, а нижнее изображение должно быть таким как верхнее

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Размер изображения 200x200 пикселей

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался))))

```
private void getPixelFromHaos(){
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mImageViewHaosCenter.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();
    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    int curPixel;
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            // get current index in 2D-matrix
            int index = x * width + y;
            curPixel = bitmap.getPixel(y, x);
            if (curPixel == Color.WHITE){
                pixels[index] = 0;
            }
            else{
                pixels[index] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    Bitmap bitmapBottom = checkBitmap(pixels, width, height, bitmap.getConfig());
    mImageViewHaosBottom.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmapBottom));
}

private Bitmap checkBitmap(int[] pixels, int width, int height, Bitmap.Config config) {
    int curPixel;
    Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, config);
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            // get current index in 2D-matrix
            int index = x * width + y;
            curPixel = pixels[index];
            if (curPixel == 0){
                pixels[index] = Color.WHITE;
            }
            else{
                if (curPixel == 1) {
                    pixels[index] = Color.BLACK;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    bmOut.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    return bmOut;
}
```